# Naming private properties in Python

Tags: python

My question is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432258/private-attribute-properties-in-python), but it looks like a dead thread and the question I want to ask looks a little buried.

**Question:** if I want to use `@property` to make *private* attributes, what should I name the underlying variable?

**Code:**

```
# I want to replace "NAME" with something.
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.NAME = x

  @property
  def _x(self):
    validate_x_get()
    return self.NAME

  @_x.setter
  def _x(self, val):
    validate_x_set(val)
    self.NAME = val

  ...
```

**Explanation:** I want to use `@property` and `@valname.setter` to allow `MyClass` methods to nicely work with `self.NAME`. Answers to the linked question generally say to just make private getters and setters, but it feels like there [should be a better way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M).

**Discussion:**

- A natural name for `NAME` would be `_x` but that would make `self._x` recurse infinitely.
- `x` would be public which is not what I want.
- `__x` seems like a misuse of [mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) which is for preventing subclassing problems.
- `_x_private`, `_stored_x`, `_my_x` are all unpleasant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745138/recursionerror-when-using-property-decorator/43745674#43745674)?

Comment: Python doesn't really *do* private properties. Just prepend your attribute name with an `_` underscore and you have "privacy by convention". You say you find `_x_private` unpleasant, but you should expect it to be unpleasant because Python is not designed to have private attributes. That seems like the best solution to me, so, I think you might as well just deal with the unpleasantness

Comment: This seems almost entirely opinion-based, especially since you seem well aware of the various standards and options.

Comment: Yeah, it's up to the dev to decided whether `_x_` makes more sense than `_px` or the examples you listed. I think it's more important to __be consistent__ with whatever internal scheme you choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to sum up the discussion:

- This is mostly opinion-based because Python's "private" is by convention;
- Any solution that's **readable**, **understandable**, and **consistent** is good enough.

In that spirit, I'll be advocating for `_x_` in my codebases (fewest additional characters). Thanks to all the commenters.